# Having proved $(A\wedge \neg C)\rightarrow\neg B$, how should I proceed and show that $(A\wedge B\wedge\neg C)\rightarrow (B\wedge\neg B)$?

Tags: proof-writing, propositional-calculus

I want to prove $\left(A\wedge B\right)\rightarrow C$ by contradiction and so far I've proved that $\left(A\wedge \neg C\right)\rightarrow\neg B$, now If I can show that $\left(A\wedge B\wedge\neg C\right)\rightarrow \left(B\wedge\neg B\right)$ it means that $\left(A\wedge B\wedge\neg C\right)$ which is negation of $\left(A\wedge B\right)\rightarrow C$ is a contradiction so my proof gets complete. How should I proceed and show that? I know by truth table one can show it, but is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the proof done in Fitch:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1) $A \land B$ --- premise

2) $A$ --- from 1) by $\land$-elim (or [Simplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination))

3) $B$ --- from 1) by $\land$-elim (or [Simplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination))

4) $\lnot C$ --- assumed [a]

5) $A \land \lnot C$ --- from 2) and 4) by $\land$-intro ([Conjunction introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_introduction))

6) $(A \land \lnot C) \to \lnot B$ --- already proved

7) $\lnot B$ --- from 5) and 6) by $\to$-elim ([Modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens))

Now we have the sought contradiction with 3) and 7) and we can derive, by [Contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction):

8) $C$ --- discharging [a]

> 9) $(A \land B) \to C$ --- from 1) and 8) by $\to$-intro ([Implication introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof)).

Comment: And this is fitch system right?

Comment: @Pooria - more or less... Natural Deduction.

Comment: I think as you've mentioned I should've used natural deduction in the first place and should start using it from now on for my poofs, Bram28's answer was a direct answer to my question thou.

Comment: So is "theorem introduction" the rule of inference for line 6?